# Rails: Get the image src only

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Does rails have a way to get JUST the src of an image as a string? I'm trying to embed the image on a third party site in javascript.

This is the general idea (widget.js.erb):

```
var widgetImage = new Image();
widgetImage.src = "<=% Some groovy ruby code to just get the image src as a string %>"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, you're looking for image_path

```
image_path('something.png')
```